# Selecting data from table with UUID as binary()

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-aurora

I have an AWS RDS Aurora MySQL connection. Following are the steps that I'm following to operate create, insert & fetch the data:

**create table**:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);
```

**insert into table**:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (
    UNHEX(REPLACE("9a9cbfga-7426-471a-af27-31be7tb53ii2", "-","")),
    "Jon",
    "Smith"
);
```

**fetch from table**:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = UNHEX(REPLACE("9a9cbfga-7426-471a-af27-31be7tb53ii2", "-",""));
```

The handler function that triggers my function to fetch the data goes like:

```
module.exports.fetchUser = async (event, context, callback) => {

  const params = {
    resourceArn: 'arn:aws:rds:*********:cluster:************',
    secretArn: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:*************',
    sql: 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = UNHEX(REPLACE("9a9cbfga-7426-471a-af27-31be7tb53ii2", "-",""))',
    database: 'dev_db1',
    continueAfterTimeout: true,
    includeResultMetadata: true
  }

  try {
    const db_res = await rdsDataService.executeStatement(params).promise();

    const response = {
      body: {
        message: 'Data fetched',
        data: JSON.stringify(db_res, null, 2)
      }
    };
    callback(null, response);
  } catch (error) {
    callback(null, error)
  }
};
```

Executing the http data API endpoint for the same results me in this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "message": "Data fetched",
        "data": [
            [
                {
                    "blobValue": {
                        "type": "Buffer",
                        "data": [
                            202,
                            136,
                            22,
                            206,
                            45,
                            214,
                            75,
                            233,
                            156,
                            28,
                            163,
                            223,
                            186,
                            115,
                            89,
                            107
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "stringValue": "Jon"
                },
                {
                    "stringValue": "Smith"
                },
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

All I need is to fetch the complete details of all the users (for now I've inserted just one record for ease) in the table `user` and show the exact `user_id` instead of the `blobValue`. Not sure how to convert this UUID binary into redable form like `9a9cbfga7426471aaf2731be7tb53ii2` or `9a9cbfga-7426-471a-af27-31be7tb53ii2` in the response.
I'am bit new to handling queries in MYSQL & Aurora, any help to get me through this will be really appretiated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why saving it in binary in the first place when need it back and you query the uuid anyway

Comment: @nbk Actually I have been asked to follow up with this format. We're gonna use the uuid as the primary key. So, I was trying to work using that but unable to figure out. Even if I just query like `SELECT * FROM user`, it still gives the same response in blob format.

Comment: save it as string or if you need the binary for something make another column.

Comment: @nbk Can you help with some small written examples?

Comment: no i can't you code doesn't work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=782e7933f19a22d03869a105c8862a8a

Comment: @nbk. Here, I fixed the errors: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d74a239615ac6f73c48c45bdaca26714. If now you can elaborate on the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql 8 has a function for that as https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid
and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-to-bin

But you have to do it manually.

As i can't insert your data anywhere the select will do

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (
>     user_id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
>     first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
>     last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
> )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user VALUES (UNHEX(REPLACE("3f06af63-a93c-11e4-9797-00505690773f", "-","")),
>     "Jon",
>     "Smith");
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from user where user_id = UNHEX(REPLACE("3f06af63-a93c-11e4-9797-00505690773f","-",""))
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | first_name | last_name
> :------ | :--------- | :--------
> null    | Jon        | Smith
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(HEX(user_id),1,8),'-',
>              SUBSTRING(HEX(user_id),9,4),'-',
>             SUBSTRING(HEX(user_id),13,4),'-',
>             SUBSTRING(HEX(user_id),17,12)) user_id,first_name,last_name FROM user
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id                         | first_name | last_name
> :------------------------------ | :--------- | :--------
> 3F06AF63-A93C-11E4-979700505690 | Jon        | Smith
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1860a347e66930056cc891aefe3db04c)*

But as you need the text anyway, keep the original so you don't need to unhex hex  the data again

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    userid_txt Varchar(3&)
);
```

Comment: I am unable to understand with the thing `keep the original`, what exactly this means?

Comment: every time that that yu make yur select, you have to calculate the where clause and the result, that cost time and cpu power, if you have 100 or 1000 or 50000 users at the  same time, this will cost you dearly. So make an index of userid_txt  whey you save 3f06af63-a93c-11e4-9797-00505690773f and the you use that to search and as return value for your SELECT

Comment: So, doing this will help to return the proper data format from AWS handler function without the blob?

Comment: It is hard to explain, a uuid is used instead of a integer, which is faster, because you have, you have to keep a unique identifier even when you dn't have a steady  connection or dffernet lokal databases that have to be combined. So you first want to get all uuids that have certain abilities. For rxample which users are teachers, so your first select give you already all uuids , so there is no need to recver it from your binary state. as i try to struggle why you need the uuids in plain text form, i don't see the need to convert t to binary in the first place, when you need it in plain text

Comment: In short, you mean to say that I can just pass/store the uuid directly in actual form, without the need to INSERT it in HEX form without replacing '-' and then SELECT it by UNHEXING it. Right?

Comment: no, i don't understand why do you need to reverse the binarizsation in the first pace, if you need the complete uuid later again. but as i don't understand how you have have `where user_id = UNHEX(REPLACE("3f06af63-a93c-11e4-9797-00505690773f","-","")) ` top have that inofrmaztion you must have stored the uuid soemwhere, because next time you can't build. So you make a select onb yyour dqatabase to retrieve the uuids, to use that as identifier for the row, but there is no need to convert them back, as the information is binary and you can store that in a variabe and use that to do your select.